# Tricky exponential elliptical integral

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I've run into this tricky exponential integral while trying to calculate the steady state heat distribution of a moving toroidal heat source. A simple form of it is:

$$\int_0^{2π} \frac{e^{-\sqrt{1-a\cos \theta}}}{\sqrt{1-a\cos \theta}}\, d\theta$$

Where $|a| < 1$

I've thrown many tricks at it, but each seems to balloon in complexity. Any ideas?

Maybe a Fourier transform can help, considering the offset axisymmetry that created this problem.

I have seen some semi-related literature involving toroidal expansions. This integral emerged from attempting to revolve a point source field of the form $e^{-r}/r$ into a ring.

Comment: Isn't this divergent?  Look at the denominator.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! An important clarification -> |a| is less than 1.

Comment: Possibly of use: https://web.archive.org/web/20170808233530/https://www.piers.org/piersonline/pdf/Vol4No6Page605to610.pdf

Comment: If $f(b)= \int_0^{2π} \frac{e^{-b\sqrt{1-a\cos \theta}}}{\sqrt{1-a\cos \theta}}\, d\theta$, then $f’(b)= -\int_0^{2π} e^{-b\sqrt{1-a\cos \theta}}\, d\theta $ is simpler. Are you still looking for a closed form?

Comment: Is it for numerical calculations ?

Comment: If it helps at all, you can write
\begin{equation}
 I(a) = \frac{e}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{-\sqrt{1 - a\cos\theta}}}{\sqrt{1 - a\cos\theta}}\,d\theta
\end{equation}
as a power series $c_0 + c_2 a^2 + c_4 a^4 + \cdots$ where
\begin{align*}
 c_0 &= 1, \\
 c_2 &= \frac{7}{16}, \\
 c_4 &= \frac{133}{512}, \\
 c_6 &= \frac{27007}{147456},\\
 c_8 &= \frac{5329837}{37748736}, \\
 c_{10} &= \frac{866792053}{7549747200}, \\
 c_{12} &= \frac{841146804577}{8697308774400}.
\end{align*}

Comment: The numerators are, from the OEIS, relate to [Bessel polynomials at $x=1$](https://oeis.org/A001515) while the denominators are hard to find